# Locally finite-dimensional simplicial complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am looking for the definition of “locally finite-dimensional” for simplicial complexes. I saw this term from a paper and Hatcher’s book. I believe it means that each vertex has a finite-dimensional star, but cannot find a definition anywhere. Can someone suggest a reference? Thanks!

Comment: The question is about ‘locally finite-dimensional’, different from ‘locally finite’.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual concept.

On p.138 of Hatcher the phrase appears for CW-complexes, but there is no precise definition. In my opinion Hatcher does not want to officially introduce a notion of "locally finite-dimensional" like "locally finite", but only says that that he considers a complex which is *locally* finite-dimensional in the sense that each point has neighborhood which is a finite-dimensional subcomplex. Of course you may take this as a proper definition.

In

> Sakai, Katsuro, and Hanbiao Yang. "The box topology of infinite simplicial complexes." Tsukuba Journal of Mathematics 36.2 (2013): 295-309, https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tkbjm/1358777002

you can find another occurence, but again without an official definition. However, on p.304 you can see that that a complex $K$ is locally finite-dimensional if for all $x \in \lvert K \rvert$ one has $\dim \text{St}(c_K(x),K) < \infty$, where $c_K(x)$ is smallest simplex of $K$ containing $x$.

More references:

> Mine, Kotaro, and Katsuro Sakai. "Simplicial complexes and open subsets of non-separable LF-spaces." Canadian Journal of Mathematics 63.2 (2011): 436-459, https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/D3839E401164F0ECFF6C9176EF1C859A/S0008414X00006684a.pdf/simplicial_complexes_and_open_subsets_of_nonseparable_lfspaces.pdf

Footnote 2 on p. 437 says "A simplicial complex $K$ is locally finite-dimensional if each vertex $v$ of $K$ has the finite-dimensional
star, that is, $\sup \{\dim \sigma| v \in \sigma \in K \} < \infty$."

> Mardešić, Sibe, and Nikica Uglešić. "On irreducible mappings into polyhedra." Topology and its Applications 61.2 (1995): 187-203, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686419400027Z

A definition occurs in section 3.

> Sakai, Katsuro. Geometric aspects of general topology. Japan: Springer, 2013.

A definition occurs on p. 145.